# Checkbox cannot display in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am building a html page using dom concept, but the checkbox is not displaying in the html page. My code is below.

```
if (condition <= 0) {
 $doc = $(document.createElement("li")).attr({
     id: id,
     name: name,
     'class': 'liBullet'
 })
}

else {
 $doc = $(document.createElement("ul")).attr({
     id: id,
     name: name,
     'class': 'liBullet'
 })
}

$doc.append(
    $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
     id: id,
     type: "checkbox",
     name: name,
     'class': 'layerCheck'
    })

    .append(
        $(document.createElement("label")).attr({
          id: id,
          name: name
        })
    ).text(name)

    .append(
        $(document.createElement("div")).attr({
         id: id,
         'class': 'loadingLegend'
        })
    )).appendTo("#layer_list");
}
```

Comment: I hope you are not using Javascript to build out your entire html page. You could must more easily just write `<input type="checkbox" name="blah" class="layerCheck" />`

Comment: but my client need to asj this type only thats y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document.createElement("input")).attr({
                                     id: layer.id,
                                     type: "checkbox",
                                     name: layer.name, // <---- missing comma?
                                     'class': 'layerCheck'
                                 }); // <-- or missing semicolon?
```

Also, you don't need to use `createElement`, you can just do:

```
$("<input />").attr({
                       id: layer.id,
                     type: "checkbox",
                     name: layer.name,
                  'class': 'layerCheck'
              }).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: thats the not problem i need to append the some pther data so i didnot use the ; any other idea?

Comment: @user279 Then post the whole statement! How can he evaluate your syntax if you are only giving him part of the statement?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this :

```
$("<input type='checkbox' id='id' name='name' value='val'/>").appendTo("body");
```

or

```
$("body").append("<input type='checkbox' id='id' name='name' value='val'/>");
```

read about [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) & [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)